# Error with this php code

Tags: php

I am seeing this error on my website.

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
>   be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/u857740002/public_html/datafetch.php on line 3
>
> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
>   be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/u857740002/public_html/datafetch.php on line 23

I am using this code.

Can anyone correct these two lines.

```
$siteSettings = mysql_query("select * from pu_settings where sid = '1' ");
$siteSoft = mysql_query("select * from pu_softwares where slug = '$slug' ");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: This is a warning you can still use mysql_query but its old and unsafe, use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php instead, or the next generation http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL_* is deprecated and is going to be removed very soon with PHP. Use MySQLi_*. 
See: [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Use this instead:

```
$link = mysqli_connect([dbhost],[dbusername],[dbpass],[dbname]);

$siteSettings = mysqli_query($link,"select * from pu_settings where sid = '1' ");
$siteSoft = mysqli_query($link,"select * from pu_softwares where slug = '$slug' ");
```

Comment: Is it right what you wrote because my knowledge says that mysqli_query need two parameters that is connection object and query. You are giving query only, where is connection object?

Comment: it solved my problem. but now a blank screen is showing up. how to solve this problem

Comment: mysqli_query() takes two parameters. how it solved. if you run this codeit will give you error.

Comment: Forgot the first parameter.The first parameter should be the link to the connection, returned from mysqli_connect().
`mysqli_query($link,$query)`. View the edited answer.

Comment: you are right @anantkumarsingh . my site is showing blank screen only. how to solve it?

Comment: Try to use this on each page at starting after `<?php` started :-

`<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_*` is deprecated+removed library so use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`:-

suppose your database connection object is `$conn`

```
$siteSettings = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from pu_settings where sid = '1' ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$siteSoft = mysql_query($conn,"select * from pu_softwares where slug = '$slug' ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

The code to create a connection using `mysqli_*` is:-

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","databasename");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` in your query.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$siteSettings = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pu_settings where sid = '1' ");
$siteSoft = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pu_softwares where slug = '$slug' ");
```

Comment: Is it right what you wrote because my knowledge says that mysqli_query need two parameters that is connection object and query. You are giving query only, where is connection object?

Comment: temporal blindness..:)

Comment: You could also use the oop style, which is more convenient if you're firing more queries then only one: `$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM world WHERE people='awesome')`